# Why is double time speed different on iPod vs iPhone?

Tags: ipod, iphone, podcasts, podcasts.app

I have a 6th gen iPod Nano (software version 1.2) and an iPhone 4S (iOS 6.0.1) . On the iPod, I have options to listen to podcasts at ½x, 1x, and 2x time. On the iPhone Podcasts app version 1.1.2 (209), I have options for ½x, 1x, 1.5x, 2x, and 3x time. If I listen to a podcast at 1x speed on both devices, it unsurprisingly sounds the same. However, if I listen to a podcast at 2x speed on both devices, it sounds more sped up on the iPhone. The voices sound more natural on the iPod but more like chipmunks on the iPhone. Is there a reason for this difference? Why do these two Apple devices handle audio speeds differently?

Answer (score 1):

I can only offer a shot in the dark, and that is that the iPod has a weaker processor and when it tries to double the speed, the time it takes for the processor to do some calculations slows it down a little.